# Why are English translations of Field Labels shown on site's default language?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have 5 languages and all my fields are translated into them. My default language is ancient Aryan.

When I clear cache English translations of Fields Labels are displaying in default language. Other languages rest ok.

When I change English translations of fields labels nothing changes.

Only when I rename one of field labels on default language all English translations of field labels become ok.

What to do if i like to clear cache?

I described bug here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2790131#comment-11574329